# how to Left Join with Table2 results in NULL and then Table2 results with flag

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having this 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Table1_Key INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Info NVARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (Table1_Key)
);


CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    Table2_Key INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Info_table2   NVARCHAR(50),
    Table1_FKey INT,
    Flag BIT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Table2_Key,Table1_FKey),
    FOREIGN KEY (Table1_FKey) REFERENCES Table1(Table1_Key)
);
```

with values like this

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
VALUES ('Record 1'), ('Record 2'), ('Record 3')

INSERT INTO Table2 
VALUES ('test 1',1,1), ('test 2',1,0), ('test 3',1,1),
       ('test 1',2,0), ('test 2',2,1), ('test 3',2,2)
```

It is possible to do a `LEFT JOIN` with `Table2` that select all `Table1` with NULL values on `Table2` `AND` the `Table2` values with the `Flag` in 1?

Expected Result:

```
  Table1_Key    Info    Table2_Key  Info_table2 Table1_FKey Flag
------------------------------------------------------------------
    1          Record 1     NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL
    2          Record 2     NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL
    3          Record 3     NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL
    1          Record 1      1         test 1        1        1
    1          Record 1      3         test 3        1        1
    2          Record 2      5         test 2        2        1
    2          Record 2      6         test 3        2        1
```

the join I'm trying to do which is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1_FKey = Table1_Key
WHERE Flag = 1
```

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `AND` to get true `left join` behaviour

Comment: or use inner join

Comment: This is an order of operation issue.  The join occurs creating null records.  Then you exclude them by saying flag = 1.  To keep them, move the limit to the join so the limit is applied as part of the join and the null records are kept.  `LEFT JOIN table2 on Table1_FKEY = Table1_key AND flag = 1`

Comment: @HoneyBadger even if I change it, it doesn't give me the expected result. It just add the Record 3 from table one with the nulls, but not the Record 1 or Record 2 with the nulls

Comment: Consider: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cf56/12/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cf56/12/0)

Case statements on flag should do it. for each of the columns in table2 should do it.

```
SELECT table1_key
     , info
     , case when flag =0 then null else table2_key end as table2_key
     , case when flag =0 then null else info_table2 end as info_table2
     , case when flag =0 then null else table1_fkey end as table1_fkey
     , case when flag =0 then null else  flag end as  flag
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON Table1_FKey = Table1_Key
ORDER BY table2_key
```

Giving us:

```
+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| table1_key |   info   | table2_key | info_table2 | table1_fkey |  flag  |
+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|          1 | Record 1 | (null)     | (null)      | (null)      | (null) |
|          2 | Record 2 | (null)     | (null)      | (null)      | (null) |
|          3 | Record 3 | (null)     | (null)      | (null)      | (null) |
|          1 | Record 1 | 1          | test 1      | 1           | true   |
|          1 | Record 1 | 3          | test 3      | 1           | true   |
|          2 | Record 2 | 5          | test 2      | 2           | true   |
|          2 | Record 2 | 6          | test 3      | 2           | true   |
+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: So then no filter and use case statements so no records are actually eliminated; just nulled out if flag is not zero.  and w/o a union

Comment: @xQbert Now this would be more useful for me. Thank you, found it hard to solve it without `union`

Answer (score 2):

So basically this? :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1_FKey = Table1_Key
WHERE Flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: This give me the expected result, but was looking for a way to do it without `UNION`

Comment: Well , that's a problem.. A record can either find a match, or not. It cannot do both (You want for each record in table1, a row with `NULL` and a row/s with the match/es) . It's not possible as far as I'm aware of . @Ragmar

Answer (score 2):

Your expected result is not possible without a UNION being tacked on as described by sagi.

By specifying the `LEFT JOIN` condition as `Table1_Key = Table1_Fkey`, you're defining the result set to include rows from Table1 where the condition *does* match (record 1 and record 2), and rows where the condition *does not* match (record 3).

Think of it this way... if you cross-join the tables (match every record in table1 with every record in table2), you end up with this:

```
Table1_Key    Info    Table2_Key  Info_table2 Table1_FKey Flag
------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Record 1       1         test 1        1         1
1          Record 1       2         test 2        1         0
1          Record 1       3         test 3        1         1
1          Record 1       4         test 1        2         0
1          Record 1       5         test 2        2         1
1          Record 1       6         test 3        2         1        
2          Record 2       1         test 1        1         1
2          Record 2       2         test 2        1         0
2          Record 2       3         test 3        1         1
2          Record 2       4         test 1        2         0
2          Record 2       5         test 2        2         1
2          Record 2       6         test 3        2         1        
3          Record 3       1         test 1        1         1
3          Record 3       2         test 2        1         0
3          Record 3       3         test 3        1         1
3          Record 3       4         test 1        2         0
3          Record 3       5         test 2        2         1
3          Record 3       6         test 3        2         1
```

However, by specifying your join condition as `Table1_Key = Table1_Fkey AND Flag = 1`, you're restricting the result set to those rows where that condition is true:

```
Table1_Key    Info    Table2_Key  Info_table2 Table1_FKey Flag
------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Record 1       1         test 1        1         1
1          Record 1       3         test 3        1         1
2          Record 2       5         test 2        2         1
2          Record 2       6         test 3        2         1
```

And because it's a `LEFT JOIN`, any records from Table1 that DID NOT find a match on Table2 will be included:

```
Table1_Key    Info    Table2_Key  Info_table2 Table1_FKey Flag
------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Record 1       1         test 1        1         1
1          Record 1       3         test 3        1         1
2          Record 2       5         test 2        2         1
2          Record 2       6         test 3        2         1        
3          Record 3      NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL
```

So, in order to get the result set you're looking for, you would need to explicitly `UNION` on the extra rows from Table1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1_FKey = Table1_Key AND Flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Table1_Key in (1,2)
```

... to obtain your desired result:

```
Table1_Key    Info    Table2_Key  Info_table2 Table1_FKey Flag
------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Record 1       1         test 1        1         1
1          Record 1       3         test 3        1         1
2          Record 2       5         test 2        2         1
2          Record 2       6         test 3        2         1        
3          Record 3      NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL       
1          Record 1      NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL       
2          Record 2      NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL
```

Comment: insn't table2_key the incorrect expected result? all 1's?  when the set should be {NULL, NULL, NULL,1,3,5,6}

Comment: @TruAvatar your answer was really good, but @xQbert posted now a solution without `Union`. You help me understand a bit more of SQL. Thank you

Comment: That `CASE` method does spit out the result you're after in this instance, but be careful when working with real data. If you happen to have two rows in Table2 with Table1_Fkey = 1 and Flag = 0, you'll get duplicate rows of {1, Record 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}. This may not be an issue for what you're doing, but be aware.

Answer (score 1):

Check this query:

1. Selected values from Table 1
2. Union all
3. Fetch Values based on condition and left join

   ```
   SELECT        Table1_Key, Info, NULL AS Expr3, NULL AS Expr4, NULL AS Expr5, NULL AS Expr6
   FROM            Table1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT        Table1_1.Table1_Key, Table1_1.Info, Table2.Table2_Key, Table2.Info_table2, Table2.Table1_FKey, Table2.Flag
   FROM            Table2 LEFT JOIN
                    Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table2.Table1_FKey = Table1_1.Table1_Key
   WHERE        (Table2.Flag = 1)
   ```

*Output :*

[image]

Comment: This is basically the same as @sagi, but as I told him, I would have like it to be without `UNION`